# How to set variables such as probabilities to turtles one at a time locally in NetLogo

Tags: variables, netlogo

In NetLogo I would like to iterate through each turtle one-at-a-time, with two breeds; bigs and smalls. In looking at one turtle, I would like to assign its neighbours probabilities, then make those probabilities into a list, multiply the list and then use that value to decide if the turtle should be moved or not. Then once the loop has finished working on one turtle, these values should be lost so they don't impact on the next central turtles neighbourhood. I have been using this code, but I realise now it seems to be overwritting the values as the 'ask smalls' comes last in the Probability_Product but I'm not sure how to fix it. Most of the undefined variables here are on a slider in the GUI.
Thanks!

```
   breed [ bigs big ]
breed  [ smalls small ] 
bigs-own [ probability]
  smalls-own [ probability]


to setup
  clear-all 
  set-default-shape bigs "square"
  set-default-shape smalls "square"

   ask n-of bigs-number patches with [ abs (min-pxcor - pxcor) > 2]
    [sprout-bigs 1 [ set color red ]] 

    ask n-of smalls-number patches with [not any? bigs-here] 
     [sprout-smalls 1 [ set color blue ]]

    reset-ticks
end


to go  
ask turtles with [count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ][  
  ;; so only turtles will a space in the neighbours 4 can move
       let vacant-patches neighbors4 with [not any? turtles-here ]
  ;print Probability_Product 

if count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 [
             if random 1001 <= Probability_Product * 1000    ;;if random number in the probability range, the following happens 
                     [ move-to one-of vacant-patches ]]
     ]
  tick
end

to-report Probability_Product  
  if ( count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ) or ( count turtles-on neighbors4 = 0 ) [

ifelse breed = bigs 

[  ask bigs-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_big_big_breaking]  ask smalls-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_small_big_breaking]
   let prob-list ( sentence ([probability] of turtles-on neighbors4))
  print prob-list
ifelse prob-list != [] 
 [ report reduce  * prob-list ] ;; multiplies all the probabilities together
       [report 1 ]]

[  ask smalls-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_small_small_breaking]  ask bigs-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_small_big_breaking]
  let prob-list ( sentence ([probability] of turtles-on neighbors4))
  print prob-list
ifelse prob-list != [] 
 [ report reduce  * prob-list ] ;; multiplies all the probabilities together
       [report 1 ]]]

 end
```

Comment: There appears to be a closing square bracket missing near the end of the first block code.  Also, what happens if `prob-list = []`?  Can that happen?  What is reported?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds as if it might be helpful to have two probability variables, called, for example, `new-probability` and `old-probability`.  Update one in terms of the other, so that you can keep the two different versions distinct until you're done processing all of the turtles.  Then move the value of `new-probability` into `old-probability`.  I'm just guessing--I'm not sure whether that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Mars I fixed that bracket. I have tried to simplify my very long and complex code down so I'm only focusing on the question, yes an empty list can happen, it sets it to the value 1 in my longer code (it has an ifelse instead).

Comment: Also to answer your second comment, I want to work on one central turtles neighbourhood probabilities(from its neighborhood4), multiply all the probabilities from its neighbourhood together, then move that one turtle based on that one probability. Then move onto the next turtle and do the same until all the turtles are done, then start again. Also I fixed some of my code already, I think its a little better now (re-edited original)

Comment: Does the product of the probabilities of the neighbors have any purpose other than to determine how the turtle moves?  It sounds as if it is really a different quantity from the probabilities in the neighbors.  If you don't store the probability that comes from the multiplication, then there will be no problem with using probabilities that have been modified during the loop, because no *stored* probabilities will be modified.  If you *do* need to store the product, and use it later, it still seems like it should be in a different variable than the probability that goes into the multiplication.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about the purpose of the probabilities.  Here are some related questions.  How do probabilities get values in the first place?  Will they always have the values `Prob_bigs_bigs_breaking` and `Prob_small_smalls_breaking`?  Do they need to change?  When, and why?  This is not clear from your code or from what you've written.  (By the way, as indicated in my "answer", I've edited your code to make it syntactically correct, and to make it clearer.  Please make sure that I added brackets in the right place after the two inner `ask`s.

Comment: Thanks for that @Mars! I'm working on checking it and I'll let you know how I go. The original prob values are defined on sliders so they can  be changed (but won't be changed when the simulation is running, they just need that option for easy implementation). The probabilities need to get updated for each turtle each iteration based on the turtles neighbourhood. For example if a turtle is a big and has 1 small in the n4, the small will get the value of  Prob_small_big_breaking which determines whether that central turtle will move. Then start from scratch with a new neighbourhood when moved.

Comment: The Prob-prod purpose is as you say to just determine how the turtle moves. It only needs to be used to tell the turtle to move or not once, doesn't need to be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer (EDIT: Maybe it is now?), but it's a necessary response, and it won't fit into a comment.  I have other questions in comments.

I'm still not sure whether I've answered your question in comments.  I think there are a few things that need to be done first to clarify what your code is supposed to do.  First, I've edited the code in your question to format it in order make it clearer (while trying to preserve your style as much as possible).  Second, I added closing brackets on the line after `ask bigs` and after `ask smalls`.  Most importantly, I think that it would help if you could provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MWE)--the smallest, simplest version of your program that still contains code that (a) runs, and (b) illustrates the problem you're trying to solve.  It takes some work to construct an MWE, because you have to figure out what you can take out (because leaving it in will just confuse readers), and what you have to leave in, because it's essential to creating the problem.  (However, sometimes you'll figure out the answer to your question on your own when you try to create an MWE.)

For example, here is an MWE, in the sense that it runs, but you'll have to change it to illustrate your problem.

```
breed [bigs big]
breed [smalls small]
bigs-own [probability]
smalls-own [probability]
globals [Prob_bigs_bigs_breaking Prob_smalls_smalls_breaking]

to setup
  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 20 patches [sprout-bigs 1 []]
  ask n-of 20 patches [sprout-smalls 1 []]
end

to go  
  ask turtles with [count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ][  
     ;; so only turtles will a space in the neighbours 4 can move
     move-turtle
  ]
  tick
end

to-report Probability_Product

  ask bigs with [count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ] [ 
    ;; self is each big in turn
    ask bigs-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_bigs_bigs_breaking] 
  ]

  ask smalls with [count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ][
    ;; self is each small, in turn  
    ask smalls-on neighbors4 [set probability Prob_smalls_smalls_breaking]
  ]

  ;; Here self is the turtle that called move-turtle, which called Probability_Product.
  if any? turtles with [count turtles-on neighbors4 < 4 ][
    let prob-list ( sentence ([probability] of turtles-on neighbors4))
    if prob-list != [] 
      [ report reduce  * prob-list ] ;; multiplies all the probabilities together
  ]

  report 0
end

to move-turtle
  if random 1001 <= Probability_Product * 1000 [
    ;.....
  ]
end
```

Next, I suggest that the `ask bigs` and `ask smalls` lines should be done in a separate procedure from the function containing `if any? ...`.  Putting this all in one procedure is confusing, because in the `ask` blocks in `Probability_Product`, we refer to turtles defined by those `ask`s, but in the `if any?`, we refer to the turtle defined by the `ask` two procedures "above", i.e. defined by the `ask` in `go`, which then calls `move-turtle`, which then calls `Probability_Product`.  When we get to the `if any?`, it was hard to figure out what turtle `neighbors4` was relative, because it's defined two procedures above, and because `Probability_Product` also refers to all `bigs` and all `smalls`.

In addition to being confusing, I'm not sure that `Probability_Product` is doing what you want.  For each turtle, this procedure goes and asks all `bigs` and all `smalls` to do something.  So, if the bigs and smalls are the only turtles, `Probability_Product` asks all turtles to do something, and then for the next turtle, again asks all turtles to do the same thing, and so on.

EDIT:

It seems to me that what `Probability_Product` is supposed to do in the MWE can be done more simply with the following function.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting your intention, and it may be that in the full program there is more that needs to be done, since the function below doesn't set or use the `probability` variables at all.  Even if this isn't what you want, perhaps this example will help you think through what you need to do.

```
to-report new-Probability_Product
  let neighbor-count count turtles-on neighbors4
  let big-neighbor-count count bigs-on neighbors4
  let small-neighbor-count count smalls-on neighbors4

  if-else neighbor-count < 4 and neighbor-count > 0
    [ if-else is-big? self  ; self is turtle from ask in go procedure
        [ report (Prob_big_big_breaking ^ big-neighbor-count) *    ; if self is a big
                 (Prob_small_big_breaking ^ small-neighbor-count) ]
        [ report (Prob_small_big_breaking ^ big-neighbor-count) *  ; if self is a small
                 (Prob_small_small_breaking ^ small-neighbor-count) ] ]
    [ report 1]
end
```

The idea behind this function is that the only thing that the `probability` variable is doing in `Probability_Product` is holding the values set in the sliders.  Then those values are multiplied.  But we can just multiply those values directly.

(A number of my other comments still seem applicable.)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but I haven't made much headway. I made a MWE as you suggested and edited the original code. Still confused, whatever I do now makes it worse :( I tried to put the part where I assign the probabilities in a separate code to the reporter one but I made it worse :( Any more help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it's ok! I just had to change the ifelse line to an if line and put another if line in just incase it included the turtles with 4 neighbours as they aren't allowed to move:
   if neighbour-count = 0 [ report 1]. Thanks so much for all your help @Mars !!!!! You are a champion!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, A.D.